# Matching tables on unordered sets (arrays) with optional subsets

Tags: arrays, postgresql, join, multidimensional-array

I'm trying to match observations in two tables based on a set of characteristics.

```
Table1:
id1;set1
A;{1,2,3,4}
B;{6,9,4,5}

Table2:
id2;set2
F;{1,2,3,4}
G;{7,6,2,4}
H;{6,{1,9},4,5}
```

In theory sets are unordered and every element of the sets in table 1 should match an element in table 2, however, when the element is a subset, the element in table 1 should belong to the subset in table 2.

Result should be:

`MATCH_TABLE:
id1;id2
A;F
B;H`

"A" in table 1 matches "F" in table 2, trivially. 
Match "B","H" is more complex. The second element of set1, "1" belongs to "{1,9}", the subset in "H", and that is way the all match.

How should I model this data in Postgresql  and perform this match?

PS: Ignoring the case H, of sets with subsets, I had created set1 and set2 as arrays, ordered them, and INNER JOINed the tables on the array fields.

Answer (score 2):

Install [`intarray`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.4/static/intarray.html) extension in which you can find type `query_int` ideally fitted to your need.

```
create extension if not exists intarray;

create table table1 (id1 text, set1 int[]);
insert into table1 values
('A', '{1,2,3,4}'),
('B', '{6,9,4,5}');

create table table2 (id2 text, set2 query_int);
insert into table2 values
('F', '1 & 2 & 3 & 4'),
('G', '7 & 6 & 2 & 4'),
('H', '6 & (1 | 9) & 4 & 5');

select id1, id2
from table1
join table2
on set1 @@ set2

 id1 | id2
-----+-----
 A   | F
 B   | H
(2 rows)
```

Comment: Great! Tks! Is this solution specific to the elements of the sets being numbers? Although I used number in the original question, my actual arrays are comprised of sets of street names. Can this be run on strings? I could, of course, try to hash  each street name string into a unique number and use that.

Comment: Yes, this works on integers only. The lookup table `streets(id int, name text)` is a natural and appropriate approach.